# Importing a .dae file to Xcode, shows Z-axis facing top

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I have a .dae file, which I'm trying to import into Xcode. Once I import, the object's Z-axis points upwards and Y-axis points downwards. Which actually should be vice versa. How to fix this issue?

The below image shows, how z-axis is facing top.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the camera view to see the file on the perspective you want. See the image below.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, In the xcode, Y-axis should be facing top and z-axis down. But here its vice versa. Now when I place the object, it gets placed upside down. This is happening because of Y axis facing down.

Comment: changes the perspective changes image to upside down.

Answer (score 0):

This just a compatibility issue. Model exported by modeling software usually has size or position issue.

You can set it in scene editor.

[Scene Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv7Zh.jpg)

And the image below shows the way to change camera view.

[Camera View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJhBk.jpg)